Filtering Projected coordinate reference systems in select CRS dialog box with PyQGIS
I am writing a PyQGIS script, where for the select CRS dialog box, I only want to show the projected coordinate Systems.

Is there a way to make such a choice inside the parameter definition as follows:
self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterCrs(
        'Output Projection',
        'CRS',
        defaultValue="EPSG:4326"
    )


I believe, its not possible to filter certain CRS (or CRS groups) within the automatically generated ProjectionSelectionWidget. My approach would be to create a QGIS-Plugin (not the processing provider template, which, i believe, you are using) and subclass the QgsProjectionSelectionWidget. From there you could disable the unwanted CRS.
